# Spring integration and Microservice communication

Tags: spring, spring-integration, microservices

I am pretty new to Spring Integration. I have an application written in spring integration which does a rest call to my microservice(spring boot application)

The request is a pure String and the request message(header+payload) has content type set as TEXT_PLAIN and my microservice's controller consumes as mediatype.PLAIN_TEXT_VALUE

When initiate a request to the microservice from the spring integration application it is throwing an error as "unsupported type"

Why does it throw error and what other alternative do i have?

I do not want or can't have JSON as request or response. It is just an unformatted string as input and a formatted string as output

Comment: It would be a big help if you could post a [complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. There could be a large number of reasons you're getting this specific error, but we can't really help without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: You need to provide your configuration and details of exactly what you are sending/expecting to receive. A DEBUG log of the interaction would be helpful too.